# woocommerce displaying products of a specific page

Tags: woocommerce

First sorry for my english, is not my first language.

So what I want to do is to get the products of a particular page, using the get variable, so this is my current code...

```
$page = 0;
if(isset($_GET['pagina'])){
    $page = $_GET['pagina'];
}
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product','posts_per_page' => 1, 'page' => $page);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 

    echo get_the_title();
endwhile;
```

I though the parameter `'page' => $page` will do exactly that... but it seems I was wrong and maybe I understood it wrong when I was reading it.

So example if I have 2 products: `product_1` and `product_2` and my `posts_per_page` is `1` what Im trying to archive is that

if I type `http://myurl.com/?pagina=1` will show `product_1`

and if I type `http://myurl.com/?pagina=2` will show `product_2`

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**: I think my english failed to communicate my problem so ima try explaning in other example

What I want is to get the products that suppose to go in the page I get tru `$_GET`
So if I have to use my own pagination, it will look something like this:

```
$page = 1;
$posts_per_page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['pagina'])){
    $page = $_GET['pagina'];
}
$start_from = $posts_per_page * ($page-1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products LIMIT $start_from,$posts_per_page"
```

Comment: Products are products and pages are pages. They are different post types, so you can't get products by page. Do you maybe mean you want to get the product by ID? Such that if the variable is 1 you get product 1?

Comment: @helgatheviking I dont want the product ID, I just want a pagination controls, but instead of buttons I want to control the page I go with the GET variable so my java program can read it,  would I have to implement my own?, all this is stored in the db, so the query can just return the products that are supose to go in page 2, example: `SELECT * FROM Products LIMIT $offset,10`

Comment: @helgatheviking I dont want to get the pages, I want to get the products that are supose to go in the given page